# Having to press submit button twice to submit the form. Why do I have to click twice for an event to fire in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

*I don't get where it went wrong? How to make it work on the first click? Why do I have to click twice for an event to fire in react?*
For the first time if i click, it does not do anything. It submits the form only after second click. Why is this happening? If anyone can help me fix this issue and tell me where it went wrong?

````
export class Signup extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            full_name: "",
            email: "",
            confirm_email: "",
            password: "",
            secureEntry: true,
            showTerms : false,
            showPrivacy : false,
            errors : [],
            termsAccepted : false,
            buttonActive : false,
            visible: false,
            showError: false,
        }
        this.register = this.register.bind(this);
        
    }

    onBlur = () => {
     var { full_name, email,  confirm_email, password, termsAccepted} = this.state;
     var a = full_name.length > 0  && email.length >0 && confirm_email && password.length >0 && termsAccepted
     this.setState({buttonActive: a})
     
    }
    OnPressSignin = () => {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Signin');
      this.setState({
        full_name: "",
        email: "",
        confirm_email: "",
        password: "",
        secureEntry: true,
        showTerms : false,
        showPrivacy : false,
        errors : [],
        termsAccepted : false,
        buttonActive : false,
        visible: false,
        showError: false,
    })
    }
    onPressBackbutton = ()=>{
      this.props.navigation.goBack();
      this.setState({
        full_name: "",
        email: "",
        confirm_email: "",
        password: "",
        secureEntry: true,
        showTerms : false,
        showPrivacy : false,
        errors : [],
        termsAccepted : false,
        buttonActive : false,
        visible: false,
        showError: false,
    })
    }
    onEndEditing = () => {
      this.setState({
        showError: !this.state.showError
      })
    }
    async componentDidMount() {}

    // Check if the input matches the regex requirements or not
    validateInput = () => {
      var errorArray = [];  
      this.setState({errors:[]});
       var { full_name, email,  confirm_email, password} = this.state;
       //validate emty field value
       var emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
       var passwordRegex = /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[=+\-^$*.\[\]{}()?"!@#%&/\\,><':;|_~`])\S{8,99}$/;
       if(full_name.length == 0 && email.length ==0  &&  confirm_email.length ==0 && password.length ==0 && !this.state.termsAccepted){
        errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Attention! Please fill in your Name.']
       }else{
       if(full_name.length == 0){
        errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Attention! Please fill in your Name.']
       }
        else if(email.length ==0  &&  confirm_email.length ==0){
        console.log("1");
        errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Attention! Please fill in your email address.']
        }    else if(email.length ==0){
              console.log("3");
              errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Attention! Please fill in your email address.']
            } else if(!emailRegex.test(email)){
              console.log("4");
              errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Attention! Please fill in valid email address.']
             
            } else if(email != confirm_email){
              console.log("5");
              errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Attention! Email and confirm email does not match.']
              
            }
         else if(password.length ==0){
          console.log("6");
          errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Attention! Please fill in Password.']
         
        }else if(!passwordRegex.test(password)){
          console.log("7");
          errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Attention! Please fill valid Password.']
        }
         else if(!this.state.termsAccepted){
          console.log("7");
          errorArray = [...errorArray, 'Please accept Terms and conditions.']
        }
      }
        console.log("error");
        console.log(errorArray);
        this.setState({errors: [...errorArray]});
        return (errorArray.length <= 0);
    }
    async  register() {
        var email = this.state.email;
        var password = this.state.password;
        var full_name = this.state.full_name;
        if(this.state.errors.length > 0 ){
          this.setState({
            showError: true
          })
        }
        if(this.validateInput()){
          try {
            console.log(' Sign-up Confirmed '+ email +" "+ password);
          await Auth.signUp(
              { username: email,
                password: password,
                attributes: {
                  given_name: full_name,
                  email: email,
                  'custom:TOU_version': '1.3',
                  'custom:PP_version': '1.3'
                } 
            });
          console.log(' Sign-up Confirmed');
          this.props.navigation.navigate('SignupConfirmation',{username: email});
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(' Error signing up...', error);
          this.setState({errors:[error.message]});
        }
        }
       
    }
    
    
                        <TouchableOpacity style={ this.state.buttonActive ? styles.buttonAddFamilyActive : styles.buttonAddFamily } 
                        onPress={this.register}>
                            <View style={{justifyContent:'space-between',flexDirection:'row'}}>
                            <View style = {{flex : 1}}>
                            <View style={{...styles.ikoncontainer, position:'absolute' , left : 20}}>
                                </View>
                                <CText style={{color:'white', textAlign: 'center',fontWeight:'700',fontSize:15}}>{'SUBMIT'}</CText>
                            </View>
                            </View>
                        </View>
        );
    }
    }
    ```
Here im using Keyboard scrollview, Touchable Opacity
````

Comment: There's almost 450 lines of code here. We only need the relevant submission code, please don't make us sift through hundreds of lines of code to find it

Comment: Please do try to distill your code snippet into a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example, this is a lot of code to sift through to even begin to start debugging. What constitutes the "form", and what is the "submit" function?

Comment: Hey sorry, deleted unnecessary code. Please have a look

Comment: Try deleting everything except the code used to submit the form -- would then be easier for you and us to work on.

Comment: i did remove  everything except the code used to submit the form...i put up the conditions too as There could be a catch in that.